# What does the Treasure hunter perk actually do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The Treasure hunter perk reads:

> Treasure hunter - 50% greater chance of finding special treasure

What is "special treasure" and does 50% actually make a big difference? Is it 50% of 0.01% to find a special item off of a mob?

Comment: Where on the skill map can I find this perk?

Comment: @spugsley in the Lockpicking skill tree

Comment: Regarding your "50% of 0.01%" comment. With 0.01%, you'd expect to find a special treasure in 1 out of 10,000 chests. With 0.015%, you'd expect to find a special treasure in 1 out of 6667 chests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Special Treasure means enchanted items. (Pretty much any items with magical properties)
I've tested around with this, and yes there is quite a difference but only from chests. Haven't noticed any difference on mobs. Normally you get to loot what the NPC is wearing and holding. I don't believe that they randomly generate loot when they die.